# Accessing nested array of documents containing collections with Firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the resultant array of collections that has documents mapping to their respective collections in firebase v9.

For example, I have this working:

```
  const docRef = doc(firestoreDb, "HOUSE_PAYMENTS", 'BUILDING', "SUITE_355620", '355620');
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists()) {
  // this works, it outputs the data for 355620
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
```

but I don't want to statically define the collection `SUITE_355620` and document `355620`, I need the entire array, so is it possible to do it like this?

```
  const docRef = doc(firestoreDb, "HOUSE_PAYMENTS", 'BUILDING');
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    // this currently results in an empty object, can't figure out why
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
```

at the moment I am getting an empty object. Any thoughts?
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain your database structure? Like each `building` can have multiple `house_payments`? If so, then restructuring your database to `buildings > {building} > payments -> {payment}` might be better imo.

Comment: Your data structure could use some work, I assume. If the first Firestore request works, then so does the second; this means your Firestore document `HOUSE_PAYMENTS/BUILDING` is an empty doc. It does however have a sub-collection `SUITE_355620`. I assume that you're stumbling about the "collection-document" structure of Firestore. [Start here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data), then consider what @Dharmaraj posted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [working as expected](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

> If there is no document at the location referenced by docRef, the resulting document will be empty and calling exists on it will return false.

You probably have a sobcollection but no document there.

Please provide a screen-shot of your data, if this doesn't answer the query.